# What's the UV map for creeper.png?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a Minecraft texture pack (Minebit), and I'm working on the creeper. But only the head seems right, everything else looks weird. Here's `creeper.png` (you might have to zoom in):

[image: creeper.png]

Can anyone help, at least with the format of the creeper texture?

Comment: To close voters: Resource packs are a Minecraft feature, they have nothing to do with game development.

Answer (score 5):

The following is the mapping of the texture as found [here](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/resource-packs/resource-pack-discussion/1256183-mob-skin-templates-wither-bat-and-witch-added)

[image: Creeper template]

I found it with a Google search for *minecraft creeper texture template*

Comment: The creeper looks weirder now.

Comment: @iDoProgramming: Can you define "weirder"?

Comment: Everything is misplaced, and the head is half invisible